# How does the nesting ordering of HTML elements affect CSS specificity?

Tags: html, css

I am well aware of CSS specificity rules (I have gone through this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), but I have an example where specificity of two elements should NOT be equal, and yet CSS rules are being applied differently depending on the nesting ordering of the html elements.

```css
h4 small {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- will be red -->
<h4>
  <a href="www.example.com">
    <small>test</small> .
  </a>
</h4>

<!-- will be blue -->
<h4>
  <small>
       <a href="www.example.com">test</a>
    </small>
</h4>
```

Reproduced here: https://jsfiddle.net/u39zsmx1/

`h4 small` should be more specific than `a`, yet, when the `a` element is the most inner nested element, its style wins. Why?

Comment: Notice how in the first example the underline of the `a` is still blue.

Comment: What does that have to do with the question? And why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does the nesting ordering of HTML elements affect CSS specificity?

It doesn't.

> h4 small should be more specific than a, yet, when the a element is the most inner nested element, its style wins. Why?

`h4 small` matches the `<small>` element. It doesn't match the `<a>` element. Specificity only matters when multiple rules match the *same* element.

The `a` is blue (or purple depending on if it is visited or not).  This comes from the CSS rules in the browser stylesheet.

The `small` is red. This comes from the CSS rules in the author stylesheet.

The text node is the colour of the element it is a child of.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more digging in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity, it turns out that while ordering is not taken into account, what matters is which elements are being targeted.

Specificity is not calculated if one of the CSS rules directly targets an element and the other does not. Inheritance is not applied in such a case.